# Socket in sails.js from node app

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, handshake

I have a system with a front end based on Sails that handle viewing operations on a server.
I need some back-end operation to proceed so I try to implement a node.js application that connects to sails.js using socket.io.

On Sails side, I have a controller with the following method :

```
init: function(req, res, next) {
  Watcher.find().exec(function (err, watchers) {
    Watcher.subscribe(req.socket, watchers);
  });
},
```

On the client side, I do the minimum operation :

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1337");
```

Sails starts without any problem, listening on default port 1337. I checked that doing the ssh command `netstat -la | grep 1337`

When I start the 2nd application doing a `node app.js` I get the following error :

```
warn: handshake error No cookie transmitted with socket.io connection. 
Are you trying to access your Sails.js server via socket.io on a 3rd party domain? 
If you're ok with losing users' session data, you can set `authorization: false` to disable cookie-checking. 
Or you can send a JSONP request first from the client to the Sails.js server to get the cookie (be sure it's the same domain!!)
```

At this point, I am stuck.
Some of you would have an idea ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You said you have a "front end based on Sails", but Sails is purely a back-end framework.  Then you said you "implement a node.js application that connects to sails.js"--is this application another Sails app?  Why do you need two?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, I am using sails as a front end.

Comment: It's not right or wrong, it's just not possible!  Sails doesn't run in the browser, so it can't be used for your front end like Angular or Bootstrap (two front-end frameworks).  See [What is Sails?](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/gettingStarted/What-Is-Sails.md) for an explanation.  If you mean that you're using Sails to serve your views, that's fine, but you don't need a whole other Node app to do back-end processing; you can do it all with one Sails app.  Check out [SailsCasts](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/) for info on building full-stack Sails projects!